# Transform a grammar G into LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar

I have the following grammar and I need to convert it to LL(1) grammar

```
G = (N; T; P; S) N = {S,A,B,C} T = {a, b, c, d}
P = { 
S -> CbSb | adB | bc
A -> BdA | b
B -> aCd | ë
C -> Cca | bA | a 
}
```

The point is that I know how to convert when its just a production, but I can't find any clear method of solving this on the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a job for ComputerScience.StackExchange as I don't see an actual coding question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Co-Sci

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove left recursion, direct and indirect.
2. Build an `LA(k)` table. If there's no ambiguity, the grammar (and the language) is `LL(k)`.

The obvious left recursion in the grammar is:

```
S ==> C... ==> C...
```